# Prevent Duplicated Usernames causing Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After clicking the button "Sign Up", the app is suppose to run a function in which it checks whether the username the user entered is already taken. If it is, it will stop the "creating account" process to tell user to enter in another username.

However, after entering in the same username and clicking the sign up button, it crashes my app with a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. Error line is commented below.

It would be really appreciated if someone can help me.

Database JSON file:

```
{
  "usernames" : {
    "itsandyjiang" : "0vFQYnfIbahHdC1RsuNMW45HYNR2"
  },
  "users" : {
    "0vFQYnfIbahHdC1RsuNMW45HYNR2" : {
      "email" : "andyjiang55@yahoo.com",
      "username" : "itsandyjiang"
    }
  }
}
```

Function that checks whether user entered in a username that is not taken:

```
 func isValidUsername(username: String) {
        let usernameRegex = ".{3,}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", usernameRegex).evaluate(with: username)

        if valid {
            valid = !username.contains("Invalid username id")
        }

        if valid == false {


            usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME MUST BE AT LEAST 3 CHARS"
            usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)

        } else {

            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://testapp-testtest.firebaseio.com/")
            let usernamesRef = ref.child("usernames")

            usernamesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let usernamesArray = Array(snapshot.value as! [String]) //ERROR LINE
                for storedUsername in usernamesArray {
                    if storedUsername == self.usernameTextField.text! {
                        self.usernameVerified = false
                        self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                        self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME TAKEN"
                        self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)
                        return
                    }
                }
                self.usernameVerified = true
                self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 1.5)
                self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME"

            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
    }
```

Function that runs after clicking the Sign in button:

```
   @IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

        isValidUsername(username: usernameTextField.text!)
        isValidEmail(email: emailTextField.text!)
        isValidPassword(password: passwordTextField.text!)

        if passwordVerified && emailVerified && usernameVerified {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.errorLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                }

                guard let user = authResult?.user else {
                    return
                }


                //Successfully Authenticated User
                let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://testapp-testtest.firebaseio.com/")
                let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)
                let values = ["username": self.usernameTextField.text, "email": self.emailTextField.text]
                let usernamesReference = ref.child("usernames")
                let values2 = [self.usernameTextField.text!: user.uid]
                usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!)
                        return
                    }
                    //Successfully registered user's data to database
                    usernamesReference.updateChildValues(values2, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err!)
                            return
                        }

                        self.errorLabel.alpha = 0

                    })

                })
            }

        } else {

            errorLabel.alpha = 1
            print("Password/Email/Username verification not complete!")

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that the usernames are stored as an array in the database. Much more likely it's a dictionary. But to be sure, we'll need to see what the JSON under `usernamesRef ` looks like. Please add it to your question. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added JSON file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it to a dictionary as your attached json implies

```
 let con = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
 let usernamesArray =  Array(con.keys)
```

also there are duplicates in your current scheme , so consider setting all user data inside 1 table and don't separate them , may be this only

```
{ 
  "users" : {
    "0vFQYnfIbahHdC1RsuNMW45HYNR2" : {
      "email" : "andyjiang55@yahoo.com",
      "username" : "itsandyjiang"
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
   let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://testapp-testtest.firebaseio.com/")
   let usernamesRef = ref.child("users")

      usernamesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      let con = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
      var usernamesArray = [String]()
      Array(con.keys).forEach {
         if let res = con[$0] , let username = res["username"] as? String {
           usernamesArray.append(username)
         }
      }
      // after that check whether exists / not 

  ---
```